# Converting Angular 2 routing to Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've got a site that I'm in the middle of converting from Angular 2 to Angular 5.  What I've got a question on is how is the preload in Angular 5 now handled in comparison.  For example the code on the old angular 2 code was :

```
       .state('data', {
        url: "/data",
        templateUrl: "data/data.tpl.html",*emphasized text*
        resolve: {
            preLoad:['dataService', function(service) {
                return service.primeData();
            }]
        },
        caption: "Search",
        navOrder: 1
```

My question is how does the preload: above get handled now on Angular 5.  Thank you for any comments or help with this.

Comment: This might help you: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.router.ts

```
import { NgModule ,ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { dataService } from './service/dataService';


const router: Routes = [
   { path: 'DataService, redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

   { 
      path: 'detail/:id', 
      component: HeroDetailComponent,
      resolve: {
        data: dataService 
      },
  }

];
export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NgModule , APP_INITIALIZER    } from '@angular/core';

import {routes} from './app.router';

import { dataService } from './service/dataService';

@NgModule({

   declarations: [

      your component here 
   ],

   imports: [

      routes,

   ],

   providers: [

      dataService 

   ]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

dataService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class dataService implements Resolve {

   constructor(private heroService: HeroService, private router: Router) { }

   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise | boolean {

      let id = route.params['id'];

      let result = this.check_id(id);

      if ( result ) {

          return result ;

      } else { // id not found

          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

          return false;
      }

   }

 check_id(id){

     // check somthing return somthing or false

    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Promise requires the use of a parameter in the definition :interface Promise<T> {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Promise";
}

Answer (score 1):

To preload your module/service in **Angular 5**, you can do it through route config:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import {
  RouterModule, Routes,
} from '@angular/router';

import { DataComponent } from './data.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent }   from './not-found.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'data',
    loadChildren: 'app/data/data.module#DataModule'
  },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

You can enable preload all modules (or add your own custom preloading):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  {
    enableTracing: true, // <-- debugging purposes only
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
)
```

Comment: quick question.  In the case of custom preloading how would I achieve that.  In my example I return service.primeData();?

Comment: I would call "service.primeData()" to get the data in the Data module

Comment: Also not all of the components will have preload The route I show does have it but others don't

Comment: @yams have a look at [custom preloading](https://angular.io/guide/router#custom-preloading)